# Integers as y-axis in a morris.js line chart

Tags: jquery, html, morris.js

I have started using morris.js line chart in my html page.
Is there a way to set the y-axis to only contain integers?
Now it displays decimal numbers, but my data set only contains integers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This feature was added by [this](https://github.com/oesmith/morris.js/pull/344) pull request about 25 days ago on the Github repository. It added the option `gridIntegers` that, by default, is set to `false`. It is still not merged to the main repository. Therefore, if you want to use it right now, you have to download [this](https://github.com/t3chn0r/morris.js/blob/194caaaf15c217d58f833da2a5dab1ea0c9ac477/morris.js) version and configure like following:

```
    Morris.Line({
      element: "mydiv",
      data: mydata,
      xkey: 'time',
      ykeys: ['value'],
      labels: ['Requisições'],
      gridIntegers: true,
      ymin: 0
    });
```

Have you seen a `ymin` parameter set to `0`? That is the caveat! The y-axis will work with only integers if and only if you set your custom y-min and/or y-max boundaries. In my case it is doable as I know my data will present no values inferior to 0. Therefore, it works like a charm.

You can see bellow the difference when not using and when using the patch:

[image: Without the patch]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's the actual code I used....

```
new Morris.Bar({
  ...
  yLabelFormat: function(y){return y != Math.round(y)?'':y;},
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler solution that can be used ... This keeps the interval calculation between the lines.

```
yLabelFormat: function(y){return y = Math.round(y);},
```