# Graduate YAxis using Morris.js

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I used Morris.js to draw a chart.

I populate my data correctly and I got my chart nice.

See this picture:

[image]

This is the configuration I used for drawing:

```
var config = {
        data: data,
        xkey: 'y',
        ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
        labels: ['Individual Score', 'Team Score'],
        fillOpacity: 0.6,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        behaveLikeLine: true,
        resize: true,
        pointFillColors: ['#ffffff'],
        pointStrokeColors: ['black'],
        lineColors: ['gray', 'blue']
    };
```

My question is: How can I graduate the Y axis to have a display of only 3 values: 1, 2 and 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually no parmeter to do that in the latest official Morris.js v0.5.1.

But you can hide the y values that are not integers with the `yLabelFormat`:

```js
Morris.Area({
  element: 'chart',
  data: [
    { y: '2015-01', a: 1, b: 2 },
    { y: '2015-02', a: 2,  b: 3 },
    { y: '2015-03', a: 2,  b: 2 },
    { y: '2015-04', a: 1,  b: 1 },
    { y: '2015-05', a: 2,  b: 2 },
    { y: '2015-06', a: 3,  b: 3 },
    { y: '2015-07', a: 1, b: 2 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Individual Score', 'Team Score'],
  fillOpacity: 0.6,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  behaveLikeLine: true,
  resize: true,
  pointFillColors: ['#ffffff'],
  pointStrokeColors: ['black'],
  lineColors: ['gray', 'blue'],
  yLabelFormat: function(y){ return y != Math.round(y)?'':y; }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Or you can use a modified version of Morris.js that adds a `gridIntegers` parameter. See this question: [Integers as y-axis in a morris.js line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571807/integers-as-y-axis-in-a-morris-js-line-chart).

These parameters must be set in the modified Morris Area configuration:

```
gridIntegers: true
ymin: 0 // ymin and/or ymax (a value of your choice)
```

Or you can use the latest official Morris.js v.0.5.1 and extend it to add the `gridIntegers` parameter:

```js
(function () {
    var $, MyMorris;

    MyMorris = window.MyMorris = {};
    $ = jQuery;

    MyMorris = Object.create(Morris);

    MyMorris.Grid.prototype.gridDefaults["gridIntegers"] = false;

    MyMorris.Grid.prototype.setData = function (data, redraw) {
        var e, idx, index, maxGoal, minGoal, ret, row, step, total, y, ykey, ymax, ymin, yval, _ref;
        if (redraw == null) {
            redraw = true;
        }
        this.options.data = data;
        if ((data == null) || data.length === 0) {
            this.data = [];
            this.raphael.clear();
            if (this.hover != null) {
                this.hover.hide();
            }
            return;
        }
        ymax = this.cumulative ? 0 : null;
        ymin = this.cumulative ? 0 : null;
        if (this.options.goals.length > 0) {
            minGoal = Math.min.apply(Math, this.options.goals);
            maxGoal = Math.max.apply(Math, this.options.goals);
            ymin = ymin != null ? Math.min(ymin, minGoal) : minGoal;
            ymax = ymax != null ? Math.max(ymax, maxGoal) : maxGoal;
        }
        this.data = (function () {
            var _i, _len, _results;
            _results = [];
            for (index = _i = 0, _len = data.length; _i < _len; index = ++_i) {
                row = data[index];
                ret = {
                    src: row
                };
                ret.label = row[this.options.xkey];
                if (this.options.parseTime) {
                    ret.x = Morris.parseDate(ret.label);
                    if (this.options.dateFormat) {
                        ret.label = this.options.dateFormat(ret.x);
                    } else if (typeof ret.label === 'number') {
                        ret.label = new Date(ret.label).toString();
                    }
                } else {
                    ret.x = index;
                    if (this.options.xLabelFormat) {
                        ret.label = this.options.xLabelFormat(ret);
                    }
                }
                total = 0;
                ret.y = (function () {
                    var _j, _len1, _ref, _results1;
                    _ref = this.options.ykeys;
                    _results1 = [];
                    for (idx = _j = 0, _len1 = _ref.length; _j < _len1; idx = ++_j) {
                        ykey = _ref[idx];
                        yval = row[ykey];
                        if (typeof yval === 'string') {
                            yval = parseFloat(yval);
                        }
                        if ((yval != null) && typeof yval !== 'number') {
                            yval = null;
                        }
                        if (yval != null) {
                            if (this.cumulative) {
                                total += yval;
                            } else {
                                if (ymax != null) {
                                    ymax = Math.max(yval, ymax);
                                    ymin = Math.min(yval, ymin);
                                } else {
                                    ymax = ymin = yval;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (this.cumulative && (total != null)) {
                            ymax = Math.max(total, ymax);
                            ymin = Math.min(total, ymin);
                        }
                        _results1.push(yval);
                    }
                    return _results1;
                }).call(this);
                _results.push(ret);
            }
            return _results;
        }).call(this);
        if (this.options.parseTime) {
            this.data = this.data.sort(function (a, b) {
                return (a.x > b.x) - (b.x > a.x);
            });
        }
        this.xmin = this.data[0].x;
        this.xmax = this.data[this.data.length - 1].x;
        this.events = [];
        if (this.options.events.length > 0) {
            if (this.options.parseTime) {
                this.events = (function () {
                    var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
                    _ref = this.options.events;
                    _results = [];
                    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                        e = _ref[_i];
                        _results.push(Morris.parseDate(e));
                    }
                    return _results;
                }).call(this);
            } else {
                this.events = this.options.events;
            }
            this.xmax = Math.max(this.xmax, Math.max.apply(Math, this.events));
            this.xmin = Math.min(this.xmin, Math.min.apply(Math, this.events));
        }
        if (this.xmin === this.xmax) {
            this.xmin -= 1;
            this.xmax += 1;
        }
        this.ymin = this.yboundary('min', ymin);
        this.ymax = this.yboundary('max', ymax);
        if (this.ymin === this.ymax) {
            if (ymin) {
                this.ymin -= 1;
            }
            this.ymax += 1;
        }
        if (((_ref = this.options.axes) === true || _ref === 'both' || _ref === 'y') || this.options.grid === true) {
            if (this.options.ymax === this.gridDefaults.ymax && this.options.ymin === this.gridDefaults.ymin) {
                this.grid = this.autoGridLines(this.ymin, this.ymax, this.options.numLines);
                this.ymin = Math.min(this.ymin, this.grid[0]);
                this.ymax = Math.max(this.ymax, this.grid[this.grid.length - 1]);
            } else {
                step = (this.ymax - this.ymin) / (this.options.numLines - 1);
                if (this.options.gridIntegers) {
                    step = Math.max(1, Math.round(step));
                }
                this.grid = (function () {
                    var _i, _ref1, _ref2, _results;
                    _results = [];
                    for (y = _i = _ref1 = this.ymin, _ref2 = this.ymax; step > 0 ? _i <= _ref2 : _i >= _ref2; y = _i += step) {
                        _results.push(y);
                    }
                    return _results;
                }).call(this);
            }
        }
        this.dirty = true;
        if (redraw) {
            return this.redraw();
        }
    };
}).call(this);

Morris.Area({
    element: 'chart',
    data: [
    { y: '2015-01', a: 1, b: 2 },
    { y: '2015-02', a: 2,  b: 3 },
    { y: '2015-03', a: 2,  b: 2 },
    { y: '2015-04', a: 1,  b: 1 },
    { y: '2015-05', a: 2,  b: 2 },
    { y: '2015-06', a: 3,  b: 3 },
    { y: '2015-07', a: 1, b: 2 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Individual Score', 'Team Score'],
  fillOpacity: 0.6,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  behaveLikeLine: true,
  resize: true,
  pointFillColors: ['#ffffff'],
  pointStrokeColors: ['black'],
  lineColors: ['gray', 'blue'],
  gridIntegers: true,
  ymin: 0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's answer my question ...
However perhaps I move to use raphael.js instead of morris ...